# Unable to use Apc cache within CakePHP shell

Tags: php, shell, cakephp, caching, cakephp-2.0

So I get this famous error while try to run shell script (through browser is working without issues)

> Fatal error: Uncaught CacheException: Cache engine "default" is not
>   properly configured.

default is pointing to `Apc` cache.

```
Cache::config('default', array(
    'engine' => 'Apc',
    'prefix' => 'some_default',
    'duration' => '+1 hour'
));
```

Stack trace:

```
#0 /.../lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php(151): Cache::_buildEngine('default')
#1 /.../app/Config/core.php(381): Cache::config('default', Array)
#2 /.../lib/Cake/Core/Configure.php(72): include('/home/...')
#3 /.../lib/Cake/bootstrap.php(432): Configure::bootstrap(true)
#4 /.../lib/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php(145): require('/home/...')
#5 /.../lib/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php(100): ShellDispatcher->_bootstrap()
#6 /.../lib/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php(54): ShellDispatcher->_initEnvironment()
#7 /home/ in /.../lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php on line 186
```

Environment:

```
Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
PHP 7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (cli)
CakePHP v2.8.0
```

php -i | grep apc:

```
apc.coredump_unmap => Off => Off
apc.enable_cli => On => On
apc.enabled => On => On
apc.entries_hint => 4096 => 4096
apc.gc_ttl => 3600 => 3600
apc.mmap_file_mask => no value => no value
apc.preload_path => no value => no value
apc.serializer => php => php
apc.shm_segments => 1 => 1
apc.shm_size => 32M => 32M
apc.slam_defense => On => On
apc.smart => 0 => 0
apc.ttl => 0 => 0
apc.use_request_time => On => On
apc.writable => /tmp => /tmp
```

Cake `tmp` folder - permissions `777` owned by `www-data` user (which run apache also)
`tmp` contains `/cache`, `tmp/cache/models`, `tmp/cache/persistent` and `tmp/logs` with the same permission as `tmp`.

If I change default engine from `Apc` to `Redis` for example, everything works without issues.

Comment: I try to be as specific as possible, if you  know what  more info could help solve this issue, please leave a comment

Comment: Are you sure that you've installed **[APC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php)**, and not **[APCu](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apcu.php)**? The latter is only supported as of CakePHP 2.8.5.

Comment: @ndm YES, i have APCu installed, but why it works on browser but not with shell?

Comment: @ndm Ok, i install `apcu-bc` for backwards compatibility for php7.0, and now i get rid of that fatal error - only warnings  `default cache was unable to write 'key' to Apc cache`, which still is not solving my issue...

Comment: @ndm I get it working now, for some reason enabling apcu&apc in `cli/php.ini` was not effective, when i put same lines in `cli/config.d/apcu.ini` and `cli/config.d/z_apc.ini` it start to work! Many thanks for you for indicated me good direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Apc` for `php7.0` is deprecated, so you need install `apcu` and than `apcu-bc` - for compatibility with `apc`.

Maybe is only in my case but when i put in `.../cli/php.ini` those lines

```
extension=apcu.so
extension=apc.so

apcu.enabled=1
apc.enable_cli=1
```

Apc still not work, i got warnings:

> default cache was unable to write 'key' to Apc cache

It start to work when i create two files

`.../cli/config.d/apcu.ini` which contains:

```
extension=apcu.so
```

and `.../cli/config.d/z_apc.ini` which contains:

```
extension=apc.so
apc.enable_cli=1
```

(`z` prefix is for order, apc should be loaded after apcu)